# Assign value to report text box on open

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

```
Private sub Report_Open (Cancel As Integer)
Dim var1 As Variant
Var1=DLookup(“[Menu_Item]”, “[Thaw_Tags]”, “[ID] = 1”)
Me.Text34.Value= var1
End Sub
```

I’m trying to get a textbox to get information from a table on open, using a Report. Yet when I open the report i get the error “you can’t assign a value to this object”. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: At `_Open`is too early as no controls are availible (use this event for datasource changes or validation access rights). Use the `Report_Load`event instead.

Comment: Alright I’ll give that a try in the AM, thanks!

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your dlookup where condition is wrong. It must be
 `result= dlookup (retrievingColumnName, TableName, [whereCondition]).`

Where WhereCondition could be:
NumberColumn=1
TextColumn='This is a text'

Search for dlookup and you will see many examples.

I see you have modified your question. As suggested, controls on "on open" might not be ready for you take values. You can try to move your code to "on load" or try to set focus and then asssign value.

Comment: That is column, table, and where. I even check another database I made filled with code where it works, same format.